# Trying to return Value from database column but it keeps printing the column name and value

Tags: php, mysql, html, variables, laravel-5

I am trying to set up a dynamic site title that will be controlled by my database so I can update the database with a new title and that will reflect on my site.

I've set up my controller which looks like this

TestController:

```
    <?php

namespace SCM\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use SCM\Http\Requests;
use SCM\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
use SCM\Upload;
use File;
use Auth; 
use SCM\User;
use DB;
use SCM\Sitesettings;
use SCM\Cache;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function getSiteDetails(Request $request)
    {
        
        $siteName = Sitesettings::where('option', 'siteName')->get(['Value']);

        return view('test.blank', ['siteName' => $siteName]);
    }
}
```

My output page looks like this:

```
                <div class="form-group">
            @foreach($siteName as $siteName)
            {{$siteName}}
            @endforeach
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <?php
            $cars = array($siteName); 
            echo "I like " . $cars[0] . ", " . $siteName[1] . " and " . $siteName[2] . ".";
            ?>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <?php
            $arr = array($siteName);
            echo var_dump (implode($arr));
            ?>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            {{ $siteName }}
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <!-- @foreach($siteName as $key => $value)
            {{ $key." has the value". $value }}
            @endforeach -->
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <pre>{{print($siteName)}}</pre>
            <pre>{{var_dump($siteName)}}</pre>
        </div>
```

All of the php codes return this: {"Value":"ArtVenue"}
But I need it to be like this: "ArtVenue"(no quotes). Any idea on a solution?

**Output code of my page:**

http://pastebin.com/4UWvZtze

Comment: Why are you converting a string to an array to convert it to a string again? Weird logic...

Comment: @Cagy79 That might be the problem then?

Comment: Could you try `echo $sitename->Value;`

Comment: Also, could you include the complete output of your script in your question.  You have 6 different ways of outputtingg the sitename. I'm not sure which one you are talking about.

Comment: @Cagy79 all the outputs come out as {"Value":"ArtVenue"} except the print and var_dump ones, and okay I will. I've also tried your suggestion but I get Undefined Property

Comment: @Cagy79 I've output the code page here since SOF won't format it properly http://pastebin.com/4UWvZtze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get` method returns an array of results where each result is an instance of the PHP `StdClass` object. You should be able to access the value with `$siteName->Value` in your template, i.e:

```
{{ $siteName->Value }}
```

Comment: `$sitename` already contains the VALUE, so tI guess this is not correct.

Comment: This is not explicitly stated in the question. The question only states that the output `{"Value":"ArtVenue"}` is observed, which indicates an object value with property `Value`.

Comment: @Martijn yeah ArtVenue belongs to the property "Value"

Comment: Please mark the answer as 'Accepted' if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Martijn I know it's been months, but you was correct haha.